# How to filter both date and time together from list using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, filter, momentjs

Need to filter list from both date and time

```
let filter = alertList.filter(alert => moment(alert.updatedAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == "2019-09-20" && moment(alert.updatedAt).format('HH:mm') == "10:19");
```

Comment: and it doesn't work?

Comment: Satif -  no it's not worked for both date and time. But follow code it work for me. ```let filter = alertList.filter(alert => moment(alert.updatedAt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').isSame('2019-09-20 10:19'));```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually make it simpler by using the isSame function:

```
let filter = alertList.filter(alert => moment(alert.updatedAt).isSame('2019-09-20 10:19);
```

This will work just the same and filters up to a granularity of minutes.

Comment: I used some format option because list has different format date . Thanks for your help #Domino987 ..                                                                                                       ```let filter = alertList.filter(alert => moment(alert.updatedAt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').isSame('2019-09-20 10:19')); ```